# Need help understanding segment of code

Tags: java, sorting, for-loop, selection, selection-sort

```
public int[] selectionSort(int array[]) {

    for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        int highestIndex = i;

        for(int j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
            if(array[j] > array[highestIndex])
                highestIndex = j;
        }
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[highestIndex];
        array[highestIndex] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

I understand the concept of selection sort, but the code is confusing me. Specifically, can someone explain what is happening in the last three statements of the outer for-loop starting with "int temp = array[i];"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766209/effective-swapping-of-elements-of-an-array-in-java

Comment: You switch the places of `array[i]` and `array[highestIndex]`. To do that you make a copy of `array[i]` so you can access the value after it has been overwritten by `array[i] = array[highestIndex];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the famous swapping routine. In languages like Java, when you want to swap the values of two variables named say `a` and `b`, you have to resort to such a routine where you use a third variable to hold a value in transit:

```
int a = 2; 
int b = 6;
int tmp = a; // now tmp has a value that is _copy_ of a i.e. 2
a = b;  // since we saved a in tmp, we can _mutate_ it, now a has b's value
b = tmp; // swap! here, b = a won't work because a contains b's current value.
// now a has value 6 and b has value 2, exactly what we wanted.
```

In some other languages, a construct like `a, b = b, a` is available for this purpose, which is more intuitive in my opinion.

In selection sort, after the inner loop has found the *index* of the element that holds the highest value, you need to *swap* it with the element held by the outer loop index and that's what this achieves in that context.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. I knew that two values were being swapped, but I didn't understand how it affected the rest of the code.