# How do I Implement swap array method in main class?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class array {
    public int[] Array;

    public array() {
        Array= new int[11];
    }

    public static void swap(int i, int j, int [] array) {
        int temp=array[i];
        array[i]=array[j];
        array[j]=temp;
    }
    ...
}

public class arrayTest {

   public static void main(String  [] args) {
        array theArray = new array();    
        theArray.display(); //display array
   }
   ...
}
```

I'm thinking something like this : `theArray(0,9 arr[]);`

Comment: No. It's a `static` method. `array.swap(0,9,theArray.Array);` and your names are bad.

Comment: Please do *NOT* use a "standard" name like "array" or "arraylist" for your own class, variable and method names!  Please follow the standard conventions and capitalize the first letter of your class names (e.g. `class MyClass {...}`).  Please use the "code" tag to format your code segments, instead of manually inserting back-ticks.

Comment: Please consider using java's naming conventions. The code is conflicting where you have a class like `array` but an instance of that class as `Array`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Effective swapping of elements of an array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766209/effective-swapping-of-elements-of-an-array-in-java)

Comment: how would I display after swapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given below is a sample implementation:

```
class Array {
    public static void swap(int i, int j, int[] array) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Displays elements of the array from the end to the beginning
     */
    public static void display(int[] array) {
        // Use `for (int i =0; i <array.length; i++)` for forward navigation
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        Array.display(arr);
        Array.swap(0, 9, arr);
        Array.display(arr);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 10
```

Notice that the `static` members are class members i.e. they are one per class as compared to non-`static` members which are one per instance. Therefore, `static` members should be accessed using the class name instead of using an instance e.g. `Array.display` as shown above.

**Side note** (because it won't affect the execution of your program): You should always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. the class, `array` should be named as `Array` and the class, `arrayTest` should be named as `ArrayTest`. Also, try to avoid a name which has already been used in standard Java library e.g. you should choose a name other than [Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html).

## [Update]

As promised, posting below a different implementation:

```
import java.util.Random;

class Array {
    int[] array;

    Array(int size) {
        array = new int[size];
        // Initialise the array with random elements from 0 to 100
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = random.nextInt(100);
        }
    }

    public void swap(int i, int j) {
        if (i < 0 || j > array.length - 1) {
            System.out.println("Indices should be in the range of 0 to " + (array.length - 1));
            return;
        }
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Displays elements of the array from the end to the beginning
     */
    public void display() {
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array arry = new Array(10);
        arry.display();
        arry.swap(0, 9);
        arry.display();
        arry.swap(0, 11);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
94 50 5 90 78 33 90 61 64 31 
31 50 5 90 78 33 90 61 64 94 
Indices should be in the range of 0 to 9
```

Note that these are just a couple of sample implementations. I hope, it will help how you write your own implementation as per your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: i have a display method that prints  1 to 10 but backward                           
      public void display(){

        // int[] arr=new int[11];

        for(int i=Array.length-1;i>=1; i--){
            Array[i]=i;
            System.out.print ( Array[i] + "," ); 

        }

    }

Comment: I've updated my answer to display the elements in the backwards direction. I hope, it meets your requirement now.

Comment: Thank you! can u explain why in the main class you created the "int [ ] arr.."

Comment: This way, you do not have always the same array to be swapped and displayed. You can pass a different array to be swapped or displayed depending on your requirement. I will post a different implementation as well in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

no need for method to swap just do:

```
a[i] = a[i]^a[j] ^(a[j]=a[i]);
```